# Is it Netbeans Bug or for Convenient?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm working on NetBeans and facing the following notifications.

1) When I declare and initialize `private final int a=3;` Netbeans notify me Move the Initialize to Constructor why?

2) When I declare and initialize `private int a=3;` Netbeans notify me `field can be final` until I Initialize it in Constructor. Even initializing in `Instance Members Block` causing same problem.

Any Help? why I got these notifications?

1) Code

```
public class Testing 
{
    private final int a=3;
    static{
        System.out.println("Static Block");
    }
    Testing(){
        System.out.println("Constructor");
    }
    public static void main( String args[])    
    {
       Testing obj=new Testing();
    }
}
```

2) Code

```
public class Testing 
    {
        private int a;
        static{
            System.out.println("Static Block");
        }
        {
            this.a=0;
            System.out.println("Instance Member Initializer");
        }
        Testing(){
            this.a = 3; // when I remove this I got 1) Problem
            System.out.println("Constructor");
        }
        public static void main( String args[])    
        {
           Testing obj=new Testing();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: @PeterRader thanks updated..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`private final int n=3;`

Since the variable is not **static** i.e. at class level.

NetBeans is asking you to put it in constructor. Its not an error, just guidelines.

As said in [Oracle java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

```
public class BedAndBreakfast {

    // initialize to 10
    public static int capacity = 10;

    // initialize to false
    private boolean full = false;
}
```

> This works well when the initialization value is available and the
>   initialization can be put on one line. However, this form of
>   initialization has limitations because of its simplicity. If
>   initialization requires some logic (for example, error handling or a
>   for loop to fill a complex array), simple assignment is inadequate.
>   Instance variables can be initialized in constructors, where error
>   handling or other logic can be used. To provide the same capability
>   for class variables, the Java programming language includes static
>   initialization blocks.

Comment: just to constructor? why not `Instance Members Initialize Block`?

Comment: Check the updated answer. that link provides you more information and even related Initializing Instance Members.